# Is is possible to have a XIB then set the size and have everything scale to fit in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm new to iOS development and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible.
Basically I'm retrieving some products via a webservice and I want to display each one across the screen, 4 squares per row. Each one of these squares (with image and name of product) is a UIView which has a .h,.m and xib file. I create each view like this:

```
CategoryItemView *catItem = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryItemView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[categoryItems addObject:catItem];
```

and I position it like:

```
while (colCount < cols && items < [categoryItems count]) {
  CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake( x * colCount + pad , (row * (x-pad)) + pad*row + pad, x - pad, x - pad );
  CategoryItemView* myView = [categoryItems objectAtIndex:items];
  myView.frame = viewRect;
  [self.view addSubview:myView];

  colCount++;
  items++;
 }
```

I want to use a xib so I can layout all the elements. However I cannot find a way to lay out the xib so that when positioning the UIView like this all the elements are scaled to fit and keep their relative positions in the UIView. Is this possible?

Update: You can view a 2 class example here thats not working http://home.glasscubes.com/share/s/d57sb19

thanks

Answer (score 2):

autoresizingMask is the property you are looking for on those views.

From the docs:

> autoresizingMask
>
> An integer bit mask that determines how the receiver resizes itself
>   when its superview’s bounds change.
>
> @property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingMask
>
> Discussion
>
> When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its
>   subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask. You specify
>   the value of this mask by combining the constants described in
>   UIViewAutoresizing using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these
>   constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or
>   shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property
>   is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be
>   resized at all.
>
> When more than one option along the same axis is set, the default
>   behavior is to distribute the size difference proportionally among the
>   flexible portions. The larger the flexible portion, relative to the
>   other flexible portions, the more it is likely to grow. For example,
>   suppose this property includes the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and
>   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin constants but does not include
>   the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin constant, thus indicating
>   that the width of the view’s left margin is fixed but that the view’s
>   width and right margin may change. Thus, the view appears anchored to
>   the left side of its superview while both the view width and the gap
>   to the right of the view increase.
>
> If the autoresizing behaviors do not offer the precise layout that you
>   need for your views, you can use a custom container view and override
>   its layoutSubviews method to position your subviews more precisely.

Comment: thanks but this seems to have no difference. Do I need to set the simulated metrics etc in IB? When mt UIViews are endered they are about 150 pts square. When I look at the UIView in IB they are full size. If I set the metrics to Freeform then I can reduce the size but these do not resize either. bit lost on this.

Comment: Did you set the masks on all of the views? Can you show us how you set the masks?

Comment: Well I've got all the good autosize properties set in IB and now I've also added self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; to the views

Comment: Without seeing your project I cannot solve this for you. My best advice is to start with one square and play with the masks until it does what you want. Then add the other squares one by one. Also, dont forget about the margin masks.

Comment: yeah - I might create a new project and play around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are interested: I just created a v simple project that replicates this issue. I cannot see how the elements of the view are to get resized automatically: https://home.glasscubes.com/share/s/d57sb19

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I can, but it might be a day or so.

Comment: I took a look at it and I am not sure what you expect it to do. this line: CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake( 0 , 0, 150, 150 ) is setting the size. The masks take effect when you resize the view. So, I guess I'm looking for a better description of what you are trying to do. Is the problem just that you want layout a single row of four squares?